# pg-promise insert formatting via :name and :csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I observed this code example from the [`pg-promise` documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names):

```
   const obj = {
        one: 1,
        two: 2
    };
    db.query('INSERT INTO table(${this:name}) VALUES(${this:csv})', obj);
    //=> INSERT INTO table("one","two") VALUES(1, 2)
```

I'm trying to do something similar, here's a MWE:

```
var insertObj = {rating_text: 'Example goes here!',
                 pros: 'Example pro',
                 cons: 'Example con',
                 stars: '5',
                 product_id: '20',
                 account_id: '1'}
var insertObj['rating_date'] = Date.now()
console.log(insertObj)
console.log(pgp.as.format('INSERT INTO product_rating(${this:name}) VALUES(${this:csv})', insertObj))
db.none('INSERT INTO product_rating(${this:name}) VALUES(${this:csv})', insertObj)
```

I use `pgp.as.format` to view the SQL being passed onto postgres. The output from the above is this:

```
{rating_text: 'Example goes here!',
 pros: 'Example pro',
 cons: 'Example con',
 stars: '5',
 product_id: '20',
 account_id: '1',
 rating_date: 1520886741488}

INSERT INTO product_rating("rating_text",
                           "pros",
                           "cons",
                           "stars",
                           "product_id",
                           "account_id",
                           "rating_date") VALUES('{"rating_text":"Example goes here!",
                                                   "pros"       :"Example pro",
                                                   "cons"       :"Example con",
                                                   "stars"      :"5",
                                                   "product_id" :"20",
                                                   "account_id" :"1",
                                                   "rating_date":1520886741488}')
```

I formatted the SQL for readability sake.

This SQL obviously doesn't work as the whole object is provided as a single string and returns the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): error: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
```

I expected `VALUES()` to be formatted as in the documentation.

How come the documentation example doesn't work in my MWE? Is it because of the `db.query` -> `db.none` function swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the library version.

Current version is `8.2.2`. And automatic property enumeration was added in version [7.5.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.7.5.0).

I'm certain that you are using a version older than that, and hence the problem.

---

In general, assume that the current documentation always covers the very latest version of the library ;)

When in doubt what version is being loaded, you can do the following:

```
console.log(db.$config.version);
```

Comment: Seems you were correct I was on 7.3.3! Thanks. On another note, as you're the man to ask, what's the correct way to insert a javascript `Date()` for a default postgres `timestamp` column?

Comment: @BML91 You should never use type `timestamp`, use `timestamptz` instead. And the default formatting for `Date` is then sufficient ;)

Comment: strange, I changed from `timestamp` to `timestamptz` however when trying to insert `Date()` I still get the error `invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Mon Mar 12 2018 22:47:16 GMT+0000 (GMT)"`. -- EDIT: my mistake - I just needed `new Date()` not `Date()` :)